# Button disable/enable based on user control value change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a user control which has 3 text boxes and one combobox. I am adding these user control multiple times (say 5) in my main page. I have a button in main page which should enable/disable if any of these textbox values change or combo box selection changes ( 5*3 = 15 text boxes and 5*1 = 5 combo boxes).

I am using MVVM, so i have all these controls binded to property. Can someone help me know how i can achieve this? How to capture the event for any of the changes to either a text box or a combo box and based on the enable/disable my button?

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit of a pain sometimes, but this is a good use case for `CanExecute`/`CanExecuteChanged`.

Your button's `Command` property should be bound to an `ICommand` object. That class should probably just take an instance of your `ViewModel` in its constructor so it can check all the appropriate fields in `CanExecute`.

Then, you need to add a `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` function on that command object, so that you can call it whenever a related variable is set. The function just raises the `CanExceuteChanged` event so the button will re-invoke `CanExecute` and update its IsEnabled property.

Alternatively, you can just bind `IsEnabled` on the button, and update the bound `bool` whenever a related field changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event on the `ViewModel` of the `UserControl`. Trigger it when the buttons value get changed.

So lets us say you have your control VM.

```
public class MyControlViewModel
{
    public event EventHandler OnTextboxOrComboBoxChanged;

    private string _myTextBoxValue;
    public string MyTextBoxValue
    {
        get { return _myTextBoxValue; }
        set 
        { 
            _myTextBoxValue = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("MyTextBoxValue");
            if(OnTextboxOrComboBoxChanged != null)
                OnTextboxOrComboBoxChanged(); // trigger the event
        }
    }

    // other codes here
}
```

Now on the ViewModel where the button exists. Create a subscription to the event and add a `IsEnabled` property to bind on the button.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel
    {
        MyControlViewModel = new MyControlViewModel();
        MyControlViewModel.OnTextboxOrComboBoxChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            IsButtonEnabled = false;
            // add other process here
        };
    }

    public bool IsButtonEnabled { get; set; }

    public MyControlViewModel MyControlViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Now **this is just a code mockup**, modify the details you pass on the event based on what you need by creating your own `EventArgs`